# Add UIView to KeyWindow, How to Animate UIView Off Screen When pushViewController is Called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller, keywindow

I have added a `UIView` to my `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow` and it is working properly.

When a button on the `UIView` is tapped, I want to push a new `UIViewController` onto the underlying `NavigationController`

This all works, but how can I make the `UIView` animate off the screen, to the left, with the underlying `UIViewController` ?

Comment: If you want it to animate with a view controller, why not add it as a subview of that view controller's view?

Comment: The `UIView` is added to the `KeyWindow` because the designer wants it to appear on top of the navigation bar (taking up the entire screen)

Comment: are you opening the view in appDelegate?

Comment: I don't know what "(taking up the entire screen)" means? Where above the navigation bar do they want it? Add a screen shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate your custom view and at the same time pass the control to the mail view controller to push the next view controller onto the navigation controller's stack... Below is the example code which I have simulated. The animation of your custom view should be in sync with the view controllers animation.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30)];
    [btn setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_v addSubview:btn];
    _v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:_v];

}

- (void)btnClicked:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Btn Clicked");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0.1
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^
     {
         _v.frame = CGRectMake(-_v.frame.size.width, 

_v.frame.origin.y, _v.frame.size.width, _v.frame.size.height);
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
         }];
    UIViewController *c = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TestVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: I think you must also do [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] bringSubviewToFront:_v]; after adding subview